# Run ruby on rails development mode faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, development-mode

I want to run my ruby on rails application in development mode. But when it's running in development mode it takes around 1 minute for each clicks to load which makes my development delay for long. I am using rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7.
My web application is a school system and a very large application. How I can make it load fast in development mode.

Comment: You probably cannot. When you switch on all caching and speed-up features you will basically end up running your production configuration. Why do you want to run the application in development mode? Do you run it against a smaller development database? Why is the application still running on more a than 10 years old stack?

Comment: You are running ancient Ruby and Rails versions.

Comment: Performance of an application can depend on _so_ many things, the application itself being only one of them. It could be that your development database is too big, it could be that your internet connection is to slow, it could be that your development vm/container is under performing… you say _"it takes around 1 minutes for each clicks"_, do you know what processes are run during that time and which one takes the longest?

Comment: The recent version of Rails has some great preloaders like `bootsnap(from shopify)` `Spring` and `Zeus`. But I doubt such support is available for rails 2.3.5. I was facing same issue with a legacy app built with Rails 2.3.x and Ruby 1.8.7. Checkout with https://www.speedshop.co or https://railslts.com if they can help.